# Add external mailboxes to Outlook through Group Policy

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, group-policy

I have a support team of 15 users with an internal support email account and using Outlook 2010. The same team also manages external support email accounts for various customers that require we send from their account (so no forwarding emails to our account).

In order to make sure every one in the supports team has all email accounts set up in Outlook, is there a way to add them to the users Outlook through Group Policy? Today we add the external accounts manually so each user can see all email accounts in his/her Outlook.

Would you rather recommend an alternative method or way to manage these accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Natively, there is no GPO that would do this. If you are using Exchange 2010 and the users have a Full Mailbox Access and Outlook 2010, the additional mailbox will be automatically mapped.

You can also use Outlook and only a single mailbox but set email forward from the Exchange server. This is simple and the support team or Network admin can set this up really quickly.

Hope this helps!